# What are the major new features of CouchDB 0.11

Tags: couchdb

What are the features worth learning in the 0.11 release of CouchDB? What resources are there to learn about these new developments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Features

- Nice URLs via rewrite and virtual host rules (which you can use in tandem or individually)
- Views can reference *any* document ID so when you query with `include_docs=true` you can get an arbitrary document instead of the one that generated that view row
- Replication

  - Optionally auto-create a target DB before replicating (quite convenient!)
  - Optionally specify a list of doc IDs to be replicated instead of the whole shebang
  - Replication filters: Javascript functions that return whether a document should be replicated

#### Resources

Be sure to check the 0.11 section of the [Breaking changes](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Breaking_changes#Changes_Between_0.10.x_and_0.11.0) wiki page.

However, another great resource is Jan's writeup in the Couchio blog:

1. [Nice URLs](http://blog.couch.io/post/443028592/whats-new-in-apache-couchdb-0-11-part-one-nice-urls)
2. [Views, Joins, Raw Collation](http://blog.couch.io/post/446015664/whats-new-in-apache-couchdb-0-11-part-two-views)
3. [Replication](http://blog.couch.io/post/468392274/whats-new-in-apache-couchdb-0-11-part-three-new)