# Best way to do one-to-many "JOIN" in CouchDB

Tags: couchdb, mapreduce

I am looking for a CouchDB equivalent to "SQL joins".

In my example there are CouchDB documents that are list elements:

```
{ "type" : "el", "id" : "1", "content" : "first" } 
{ "type" : "el", "id" : "2", "content" : "second" } 
{ "type" : "el", "id" : "3", "content" : "third" }
```

There is one document that defines the list:

```
{ "type" : "list", "elements" : ["2","1"] , "id" : "abc123" }
```

As you can see the third element was deleted, it is no longer part of the list. So it must not be part of the result. Now I want a view that returns the content elements including the right order.

The result could be:

```
{ "content" : ["second", "first"] }
```

In this case the order of the elements is already as it should be. Another possible result:

```
{ "content" : [{"content" : "first", "order" : 2},{"content" : "second", "order" : 1}] }
```

I started writing the map function:

```
map = function (doc) {
  if (doc.type === 'el') {
    emit(doc.id, {"content" : doc.content}); //emit the id and the content
    exit;
  }
  if (doc.type === 'list') {
    for ( var i=0, l=doc.elements.length; i<l; ++i ){
      emit(doc.elements[i], { "order" : i }); //emit the id and the order
    }
  }
}
```

This is as far as I can get. Can you correct my mistakes and write a reduce function? Remember that the third document must not be part of the result.

Of course you can write a different map function also. But the structure of the documents (one definig element document and an entry document for each entry) cannot be changed.

---

EDIT: Do not miss JasonSmith's comment to his answer, where he describes how to do this shorter.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Thank you! This is a great example to show off [CouchDB 0.11's new
features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683146/what-are-the-major-new-features-of-couchdb-0-11)!

You must **use the fetch-related-data feature to reference documents
in the view.** Optionally, for more convenient JSON, use a `_list` function to
clean up the results. See [Couchio's writeup on "JOIN"s](http://blog.couchbase.com/whats-new-in-apache-couchdb-0-11-part-two-views) for details.

Here is the plan:

1. Firstly, you have a uniqueness contstraint on your `el` documents. If two of
   them have id=2, that's a problem. It is necessary to use
   the `_id` field instead if `id`. CouchDB will guarantee uniqueness, but also,
   the rest of this plan requires `_id` in order to fetch documents by ID.

   ```
   { "type" : "el", "_id" : "1", "content" : "first" } 
   { "type" : "el", "_id" : "2", "content" : "second" } 
   { "type" : "el", "_id" : "3", "content" : "third" }
   ```

   If changing the documents to use `_id` is absolutely impossible, you can
   create a simple view to `emit(doc.id, doc)` and then re-insert that into a
   temporary database. This converts `id` to `_id` but adds some complexity.
2. The view emits `{"_id": content_id}` data keyed on
   `[list_id, sort_number]`, to "clump" the lists with their content.

   ```
   function(doc) {
     if(doc.type == 'list') {
       for (var i in doc.elements) {
         // Link to the el document's id.
         var id = doc.elements[i];
         emit([doc.id, i], {'_id': id});
       }
     }
   }
   ```

   Now there is a simple list of `el` documents, in the correct order. You can
   use `startkey` and `endkey` if you want to see only a particular list.

   ```
   curl localhost:5984/x/_design/myapp/_view/els
   {"total_rows":2,"offset":0,"rows":[
   {"id":"036f3614aeee05344cdfb66fa1002db6","key":["abc123","0"],"value":{"_id":"2"}},
   {"id":"036f3614aeee05344cdfb66fa1002db6","key":["abc123","1"],"value":{"_id":"1"}}
   ]}
   ```
3. To get the `el` content, query with `include_docs=true`. Through the magic of
   `_id`, the `el` documents will load.

   ```
   curl localhost:5984/x/_design/myapp/_view/els?include_docs=true
   {"total_rows":2,"offset":0,"rows":[
   {"id":"036f3614aeee05344cdfb66fa1002db6","key":["abc123","0"],"value":{"_id":"2"},"doc":{"_id":"2","_rev":"1-4530dc6946d78f1e97f56568de5a85d9","type":"el","content":"second"}},
   {"id":"036f3614aeee05344cdfb66fa1002db6","key":["abc123","1"],"value":{"_id":"1"},"doc":{"_id":"1","_rev":"1-852badd683f22ad4705ed9fcdea5b814","type":"el","content":"first"}}
   ]}
   ```

   Notice, this is already all the information you need. If your client is
   flexible, you can parse the information out of this JSON. The next *optional*
   step simply reformats it to match what you need.
4. Use a `_list` function, which simply reformats the view output. People use them to output XML or HTML however we will make
   the JSON more convenient.

   ```
   function(head, req) {
     var headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
     var result;
     if(req.query.include_docs != 'true') {
       start({'code': 400, headers: headers});
       result = {'error': 'I require include_docs=true'};
     } else {
       start({'headers': headers});
       result = {'content': []};
       while(row = getRow()) {
         result.content.push(row.doc.content);
       }
     }
     send(JSON.stringify(result));
   }
   ```

   The results match. Of course in production you will need `startkey` and `endkey` to specify the list you want.

   ```
   curl -g 'localhost:5984/x/_design/myapp/_list/pretty/els?include_docs=true&startkey=["abc123",""]&endkey=["abc123",{}]'
   {"content":["second","first"]}
   ```

Comment: Word, this is a thorough one. Good job jhs!

Comment: It is misleadingly long. Actually step #2 is a complete solution, however yes, I detailed background requirements and optional ways to add convenience at the client side.

Comment: The CouchIO URL has changed, here is the new one for the same article: http://couchio.tumblr.com/post/446015664/whats-new-in-apache-couchdb-011-part-two

Comment: I have a similar use case, where I need a join having mapping one to one, however I need both the docs. Following this answer I am able to emit both the docs but in separate rows using emit two times, can I do this using emit once?